# Understanding pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I've always never fully understood pointers. I'm writing this dinky blackjack game for fun on the side of my studies, and I need confirmation that this use of pointers is legitimate so I can fully understand what they do.

currently this is an example of the program and function i'm using:

```
void dealcard(int hand){
    hand+=rand()%10+2;
 }

int()main{
   int playerHand;
   ...
   *blackjack stuff*
   ...
   if(hit){
      deal(hand);
        }
```

now if I'm correct, the above would not work as I intend because the function uses a copy of the variable that is cleared before it can be applied to the original, and `hand` would never be changed.

if I changed it to something like

```
     int b;
     int *hand;
     hand=&b;
```

and changed the function declaration to include the `*`, then that would be correct.

I'm really trying hard to understand pointers and i'd appreciate any help or confirmation on this so I can understand the basic usefulness of them.

Comment: lots of guys asked similar question before, read "Related" questions in this page before anyone answers this question :-)

Comment: Are you sure about it being C++? // your code looks much more like C to me than C++.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i was reading an article about pointers that used C as an example instead of C++. also i apologize if this question is a duplicate, i realize that the community here is striving hard to keep the standard of the website high

Comment: You'd have to change to `*hand += rand()...` as well. The basic usage would be correct, but you won't really understand why they're useful by just replicating what's easy enough to do with a plain `int`.

Comment: BTW: Interesting card distribution `hand+=rand()%10+2`.

Answer (score 2):

That would be correct. It would also be C rather than C++ :-) The way you would do it in that case would be:

```
void dealcard (int *pHand) {
    *pHand += rand() % 10 + 2;
}
:
int hand = 0;
dealcard (&hand);
```

C++ has this nifty thing called references which means you no longer have to perform the sort of addressing gymnastics required by C. You can write your function thus:

```
void dealcard (int &hand) {
    hand += rand() % 10 + 2;
}
:
int hand = 0;
dealcard (hand);
```

---

And, as an aside, not really relevant to your question:

```
int()main{
```

is not one of the accepted signatures for `main`, I suspect you meant:

```
int main() {
```

Comment: interesting. so when passing as an argument of a function, i would pass by reference. thank you.